# How to render specific page template using jquery button click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this question is asked number of times and all of them didnt help me.

What I need to do is, to render template upon button click that contains mix ruby and html code.

The code I am working on is:

```
function SetLayout(val) {
    if (val == "1") {
        $("#loadContent").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:template => 'pages/template_1')) %>");
        $("#pageLayout").modal("hide");
    }
}

<div id="loadContent">
    //LOAD THAT TEMPLATE IN THIS DIV
</div>
```

**template_1.html.erb**

```
    <div contenteditable="true">
         <%= @page.name.html_safe %>
        </div>
       <div class="contenteditable="true" 
data-attr="description" id="page-desc">
<%= @page.description %></div>
```

The problem is it just render codes like below in result div

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:template => 'pages/template_1')) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot render the template directly into javascript. However ajax can be used to achieve this thing.

```
function SetLayout(val) {
  if (val == "1") {
        $.get('/your-route-to-template_1', function(data){
            $("#loadContent").html(data);
        });
    $("#pageLayout").modal("hide");
  }
}
```